# Getting undefined while trying to save x and y coordinates in an array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm drawing lines with the Raphaeljs library and I want to store the coordinates of the start and end point of the line but I can't get the correct syntax.

This is the part of the code:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

            var startX = new Array();
            var startY = new Array();
            var endX = new Array();
            var endY = new Array();


            $('input[type="checkbox"][name="check"]').change(function () {
                // proceed only when checked
                if (this.checked) {
                    drawLine();
                }
            });
        });


        function drawLine() {

            var linewidth = $("#width").val();
            var color = $("#background").val();

            function Line(startX, startY, endX, endY, raphael) {

                for(var i=0; i< 25; i++) {
                    var start = {
                        x: startX[i],
                        y: startY[i]

                    };
                    var end = {

                        x: endX[i],
                        y: endY[i]


                    };

                    console.log(startX[i],startY[i]);
                    console.log(endX[i],endY[i]);

                }



                var getPath = function () {
                    return "M" + start.x + " " + start.y + " L" + end.x + " " + end.y;
                };


                var redraw = function () {
                    node.attr("path", getPath());
                };

                node = raphael.path(getPath());


                node.attr("stroke-width", linewidth); //sets the width of the line
                node.attr("stroke", color);

                startx = (node.getBBox().x);
                starty = (node.getBBox().y);
                //console.log(startx , starty);

                //sets the color of the line

                return {
                    updateStart: function (x, y) {
                        start.x = x;
                        start.y = y;
                        redraw();
                        return this;
                    },
                    updateEnd: function (x, y) {
                        end.x = x;
                        end.y = y;
                        redraw();
                        return this;
                    }
                };
            }


            $(document).ready(function () {

                var pathLength = 0;
                var paper = Raphael("droppable", 1280, 470, 0, 0);
                $("#droppable").mousedown(
                        function (e) {
                            x = e.offsetX;
                            y = e.offsetY;
                            line = Line(x, y, x, y, paper);
                            $("#droppable").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                                x = e.offsetX;
                                y = e.offsetY;


                                line.updateEnd(x, y);


                            });

                        });

                $("#droppable").mouseup(
                        function (e) {
                            $("#droppable").unbind('mousemove');
                        });
});
        }
```

In the console log I'm getting undefined and the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: If you `console.log(startX) ` outside and inside the function does it have a value?

Comment: How are you calling `Line` ?

Comment: You aren't assigning any values to the arrays you create at the start. 

So when you call `startX[i]` for example it tries to look for `startX[0]` and doesn't find any value.

Comment: I changed it to this: `var startX = new Array()` but I'm still getting the same error. @eskimo I tried to put it outside but it's giving me the same error message. Line is in another function called drawLine() and the latter is being called using the button id.

Comment: @eskimo It works for a single coordinate but not when I'm saving it in array.

Comment: Added complete codes please check.

Comment: At which line is the error showing? 
Another thing, as you are declaring Line it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `integers` into the `Line` function while it expects `arrays`. Then you try to access the first element of the expected array inside the `Line` function at `startX[i]`. You aren't using the arrays you declare at the top of your code for anything. The arrays are also empty so the code wouldn't work even if you passed them into the `Line` function instead of integers, because there aren't any elements to be referenced to.